# Get available stables for given period MySQL query

Tags: mysql, sql

Here is the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5359/2)

Correct answer should be `864` and `871`.

And those should be the correct answer because its same as hotels if someone is checking out on a date that means that room is available on same day.

Below is the database fields

```
stable_registrations
| id | user | stableId | checkInDate | checkOutDate | 

stables
| id | name |
```

Where `checkinDate` are in `YYYY-MM-DD` format.

Expected output is

```
Available Stables
864
871
```

And I am saying this because it works same as Hotel Reservation where `checkInDate` means that customer will arrive on that day and can check in after 12:00 PM but `checkOutDate` means that customer is leaving on that day on or before 11:00 AM.

So if the `checkOutDate` is `2017-05-01` that means that stable is available on or from `2017-05-01` 12:00 PM.

If I am saving data incorrectly then please tell me the correct way to store `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate`.

I am open to suggestion to change the database models and or use unixtime if it helps in any way to get correct results.

Comment: why would the date fields declared as integer? obviously sql will interpret it as integer and not date, and that makes the current result correct

Comment: Your query seems to ask for reservations that overlap the requested dates. IOW, reservations that begin on or before the start date and end on or after the end date. If you want a list of reservations that collide with the start and end dates, use two betweens with an or. If the later is what you want, I can write an answer that shows that.

Comment: with the current sql statement, there is no way you get 864 and 871.

Comment: @maSTArHiAn I have changed the [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5359/2) with DATE format and still not correct results.

Comment: I would suggest using the SQL type TIMESTAMP, it would require changing how your dates are expressed, but would be more logical.

Comment: @SloanThrasher all i want is to know is list of not available stables for given `checkInDate` and `checkOutDate`. So that i can display user correct available rooms/stables

Comment: so what's the goal here? get who's checked in and out within a period?

Comment: @SloanThrasher If i use TIMESTAMP, i would need exact time for `checkIn` and `checkOut` right? Thats how it can be more precise.

Comment: Not unless you rent stables by the hour. Just ignore the time portion.

Comment: are you after of unrented stables for a specific period?

Comment: @maSTArHiAn goal is to get the available rooms between `2017-04-29` to `2017-05-01`

Comment: @SloanThrasher got the idea and will take it into consideration to change it in TIMESTAMP. Will it make any difference if i use UNIX TIMESTAMP?

Comment: Timestamp is a SQL data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following searches for overlap between the search date/times and the reservation date/times. It works as long as the start date has a time like 10am, and the end date has a time like 2pm (IOW, times for same date won't overlap). It also needs the reservation dates to be SQL type TIMESTAMP.

```
SET @checkInDate =  '2017-04-29 14:00:00';
SET @checkOutDate = '2017-05-01 14:00:00'; 

SELECT a.*,
  IF(b.`stableid` IS NULL,"Avalalable","Not Available") as `status`,
  @checkInDate as `avail_start_range`,
  @checkOutDate as `avail_end_range`
FROM `stables` a
LEFT JOIN `event_detail_stable_registrations` b
ON a.`id` = b.`stableid` AND
    (((`checkInDate` BETWEEN @checkInDate AND @checkOutDate)
    OR (`checkOutDate` BETWEEN @checkInDate AND @checkOutDate))
     OR ((@checkInDate BETWEEN `checkInDate` AND `checkOutDate`) 
         OR (@checkOutDate BETWEEN `checkInDate` AND `checkOutDate`))
    )
WHERE b.`stableid` IS NULL
ORDER BY a.`name`;
```

Comment: that still gives me same output. I need to know which rooms are available for whole period between `checkInDate ` and `checkOutDate `

Comment: That query returns a list of stables NOT available. To get a list of those available, you will need a list of stalls to join against. Basically, you would search for stalls that do not have reservations.

Comment: @Mike: I've added another query to illustrate how to get a list of stables that do not have overlapping reservations.

Comment: I still don't get how can i get list of available `stables` for that given period? Do i need to run 2 3 queries and eliminate results??

Comment: If you have a table with a list of stables, the last query in the answer will give you a list of stables that do not have a reservation that overlaps the specified start and end date. Do you have such a table?

Comment: are you talking about the table `stables`? it has fields `id,name` in it. I have included 2 tables in my questions and in [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5359/20)

Comment: I've edited the answer's last query to use the table name and column name.

Comment: Yes i tried that query but its not giving me stable `871` in available list see here [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5359/20)

Comment: I've changed the SQL Fiddle to show all records with an indication of available/not available, and to show the dates when there is an overlap. Take a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/de5359/59/0 If you want to find a non-inclusive (IOW, start and end dates can be equal and not count as overlap), you may have to add/subtract a day from the search dates _or_ from the reservation dates.

Comment: that is brilliant what you gave me. But i have edited my question so please read it again as i am doing something incorrect while saving `checkOutDate`. May be thats my problem.

Comment: if user wants a booking from 2017-04-28 to 2017-04-29 which is considered as 1 night stay so should i save `2017-04-28` in as `checkInDate` and `2017-04-29` in as `checkOutDate` or `checkOutDate` should be different then `2017-04-29` ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141493/discussion-between-sloan-thrasher-and-mike-ross).

Answer (score 1):

should return 868 and 869 and should not include 871 as a check-in dated 2017-05-01

```
SET @checkInDate = '2017-04-29' , @checkOutDate = '2017-05-01' ; 

select *
from event_detail_stable_registrations
where (checkInDate >= @checkInDate and checkInDate <= @checkOutDate)
and checkOutDate <= @checkOutDate;
```

or between

```
SET @checkInDate = '2017-04-29' , @checkOutDate = '2017-05-01' ; 

select *
from event_detail_stable_registrations
where (checkInDate between @checkInDate and @checkOutDate)
and checkOutDate <= @checkOutDate;
```

Comment: 871 has a check-in on may 1st so it should not be available

Comment: 871 should be available because it is `checkIn` so someone has booked it FROM May 1st. So it is available for period of  `2017-04-29` to `2017-05-01` as that person will checkOut on `2017-05-01`.

Comment: totally disagree.. as per schema (8, 5, 871, '2017-05-01', '2017-05-02'),... 871 is not available on that day.

Comment: and you after of the stables available on that day... so it's already booked

Comment: 868 and 869 are the only one's available

Comment: ok so if i am doing it wrong please correct me but it works as same logic as hotels.29/04/2017 to 30/04/2017 is considered as 1 night.

Comment: so just like that that (8, 5, 871, '2017-05-01', '2017-05-02') is booked from `2017-05-01` to `2017-05-02` that means it is available for date `2017-04-30` to `2017-05-01`. Hope you understand what i am saying

Comment: Ok what you can do is update  checkoutdate -1 day and that should solve your issue

Comment: that doesnt seem like a proper solution but i will try and see if it can work correctly.